# Facebook Open Graph Multiple objects per action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have one custom action (add) and two custom objects (favorites list) and (tv show).  I want to add TV shows to Favorites List and register it with the Facebook Timeline.  I.E. these two objects are attached to the same action.

I would like the news feed to read:

"[Joe] added [Modern Family] to his [Favorites List]."

I can't seem to figure out how to attach two objects to the same action and have them display in the timeline together.  I can either do one or the other.

Anyone have any experience in this?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should **favorites list** really be an Open Graph object?
Can a user have several **favorites lists** with different names?

If each user only has one **favorites list** (called "Favorites list") there is no reason to have it defined as an Open Graph object.

Perhaps a descriptive App name could be used to make the aggregations readable.

**[User]** added **[TV show]** to **[AppName]**:

- **Joe** added **Modern Family** to **MyFavoritesList**.
- **Joe** added **Modern Family** and **3 other TV shows** to **MyFavoritesList**.
- **Joe**, **Bob** and **3 others** added **Modern Family** to **MyFavoritesList**.

Comment: I like the out of the box approach.  I do think that my original question is not able to be done, so this might work.

Answer (score 2):

I have also been searching for a way of doing this, and I've not been able to find anything useful.

I noticed that Spotify does this without issue (straight from the feed of a friend): [user] listened to [song] by [artist] on Spotify, though looking at the 'types' documentation on open graph: http://ogp.me/#types looks like it is a custom feature for listening to music.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action from [add] to [Favorite] and have [Favorite] inherit from [like] rather than [action]

Add [Favorites List] as a custom property on [Favorite]

The title will still come up with only the object and action so:

"[Joe] favorited [Modern Family] with YourApp"

However then in the Configure Story Attachment you can add a few extra bits to the attachment in a caption e.g.:

[Modern Family] added to their [Favorites List].

Though obviously with curly braces :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can set [Favorite List] to be a property instead of a Connected Object Type and use braces on "Configure Sentences" to display it the way you want it